# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation

Tags: java, batch-processing

I have a running java batch process with the following:

ApplicationContext:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" > 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${example.connection.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${example.connection.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${example.connection.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>         
    </bean>
```

DAOImpl:

```
public void batchInsertUsers(final List<UserInfo> userDataList) {
        logger.info("userList size::"+userDataList.size());

        try{
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertUserQuery,
                    new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                            java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
                            UserInfo userData = userDataList.get(i);

                            ps.setString(1, userData.getUid());
                            ps.setString(2, userData.getFirstName());
                            ps.setString(3, userData.getMiddleName());
                            ps.setString(4, userData.getLastName());
                            ps.setTimestamp(5, null);
                            ps.setString(6, "");
                            ps.setTimestamp(7, null);
                            ps.setBoolean(8, false);
                            ps.setString(9, null);
                            ps.setString(10, userData.getUserID());
                            ps.setTimestamp(11,new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                            userData = null;
                        }

                        public int getBatchSize() {
                            return userDataList.size();
                        }
                    } );
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception occured while inserting in Users_Temp table::",e);
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

insertUserQuery=INSERT INTO USERS_temp(uid, FirstName, MI, LastName, SyncDate, Status, DisabledDateTime, Exclude, Notes, UpdateID, UpdateDateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

It runs fine everytime but once in a while it stops with below exception and I am clueless because it doesn't say anything about any data size exceeding allowed column size or violation of any constraint. Below is the exception trace:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO USERS_temp(uid, FirstName, MI, LastName, SyncDate, Status, DisabledDateTime, Exclude, Notes, UpdateID, UpdateDateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; Data truncation; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:884)
        at com.example.UserDAOImpl.batchInsertUsers(UsersDAOImpl.java:175)
        at com.example.UserServiceImpl.processData(UserServiceImpl.java:184)
        at com.example.UserMain.main(UserMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:947)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:294)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:899)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
        ... 5 more
```

Its a batch process, so there are thousands of records going into DB. Has anyone come across similar situation? If yes, please shed some light.

```
Table structure

column name       data type      allow nulls   
UID               char(9)        N
FirstName         varchar(50)    N
MI                varchar(1)     Y
LastName          varchar(50)    N
SyncDate          datetime       Y
Status            char(1)        N
DisabledDateTime  datetime       Y
Exclude           bit            N
Notes             varchar(250)   Y
UpdateID          varchar(10)    N
UpdateDateTime    datetime       N
```

UID is primary key and is indexed.

Comment: plz share ur full table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert (probably) a `String` with a length that exceeds the corresponding `column`s capacity. Either log the information about the user that you try to insert, or validate that all the data to be input is in correspondance with the size of the columns in the database. (If I were to guess, I would say that the middle name is the most likely culprit, as it only has room for 1 character.)

As an aside, read this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

As another aside, the world's longest name consists of over 600 characters.

Comment: You are right. I was trying to correct spelling mistake of UpdateID column value going as "JAVAPROCES" to "JAVAPROCESS" and ended up with this error. Its a problem though if the exception cannot tell us which column is the problem. I had to find the problem manually and suffered this long for simple mistake :(

Comment: Poor error message is an annoyance in general. I think the culprit here is SQL-server, you would get a general error message if trying to do this directly. Guess it's nothing new the MS products have the lackings and quirks..